# naming convention for "Actions" in RESTFULL API

Tags: rest, naming-conventions, best-in-place

I know that REST has no strict rules, but there are common practices to standardize it. 
I'm bit fresh in this matter. I like the idea of working on a collections so I'm using a conventions where i pluralize resources like:

```
/Messages (POST/GET/)
/Messages/1 (DELETE/PUT)
```

I also like the idea of nesting collections so I have for example:

```
/Messages/1/Attachments (Post/Get)
```

and so on
But i have a problem when it comes to custom actions like sending a message
one way it would be:

```
/Messages/1/Send (POST)
```

but I'm als thinking about something like:

```
/Message/1/MessageSendRequest (POST)
```

or maybe it's a bad idea?
In this example it fits, but in some it doesn't.
What are best practices if there is something like this in RESt :)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact, using "actions" into URLs isn't really RESTful. You should leverage a status field into the message.

Something like that for the structure:

```
{
  "id": "1",
  "title": "some content",
  "date": "...",
  "status": "draft",
  (...)
}
```

Updating the status from `draft` to `sending` will trigger the sending of the email. You can notice that there are two ways to do this update on this address `/messages/1`  :

- Using the method `PUT` with the complete payload. This can be not so convenient when the content of an email is big.
- Using the method `PATCH` with a payload containing what you want to update. There is no really conventions here. You can send only the fields to update (`{ "status": "sent" }`) or leverage the JSON PATCH format (see http://jsonpatch.com/ and https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6902) with content like this: `[ { "op": "replace", "path": "/status", "value": "sent" } ]`.

If the email is actually sent on the request, the status will be updated to `sent` .

Another approach is also possible. You can use the method `POST` on the email url `/messages/1`  . This will trigger the sending of the email. No content would be necessary and if the email is actually sent, a status code `200`  would be returned.

Hope this helps you,
Thierry